# Rendering the Text input message at button click

Tags: javascript, input, text, render

I am a complete beginner and asking question here for the first time.

I am trying to render a text that user puts in the textfield, and want it to show below my  title. Below is my code, what's the problem with this?

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>I want to pass this message to all:</h1>
    <input type="text" id="msg-text" size="100%">
    <button id="msg-button">Click to Save</button>
    <h2 class="save-title">Save the Message Below:</h2>
    <p id="save-msg"></p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" href="script.js"></script>
```

---

My Javascript:

```
let myMessage = []
const msgTextEl = document.getElementById("msg-text")
const msgButtonEl = document.getElementById("msg-button")
const saveMsgEl = document.getElementById("save-msg")

msgButtonEl.addEventListener("click", function(){
myMessage.push(msgTextEl.value)
msgTextEl.value = ""
})

let messageList = ""
for (let i = 0; i < msgTextEl.length; i++){
messageList += "<li>" + myMessage[i] + "</li>"
}
saveMsgEl.innerHTML = messageList
```

Please Help !!

Comment: check if my answer helps you. Also change href to src when include scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your message history code inside click event function. also you forgot to use correct array

just change your function to

```
let myMessage = []
const msgTextEl = document.getElementById("msg-text")
const msgButtonEl = document.getElementById("msg-button")
const saveMsgEl = document.getElementById("save-msg")

msgButtonEl.addEventListener("click", function(){
myMessage.push(msgTextEl.value)
msgTextEl.value = ""
//using myMessage array instead of msgTextEl
let messageList = ""
for (let i = 0; i < myMessage.length; i++){
messageList += "<li>" + myMessage[i] + "</li>"
}
saveMsgEl.innerHTML = messageList
})
```

Running example

```js
let myMessage = []
const msgTextEl = document.getElementById("msg-text")
const msgButtonEl = document.getElementById("msg-button")
const saveMsgEl = document.getElementById("save-msg")

msgButtonEl.addEventListener("click", function(){
myMessage.push(msgTextEl.value)
msgTextEl.value = ""
//using myMessage array instead of msgTextEl
let messageList = ""
for (let i = 0; i < myMessage.length; i++){
messageList += "<li>" + myMessage[i] + "</li>"
}
saveMsgEl.innerHTML = messageList
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>I want to pass this message to all:</h1>
    <input type="text" id="msg-text" size="100%">
    <button id="msg-button">Click to Save</button>
    <h2 class="save-title">Save the Message Below:</h2>
    <p id="save-msg"></p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks ! It worked after I moved the letMessagelist = "" part inside click function. 
I had issues with the script inclusion, I changed the attribute to "src" from "href" and it worked. 

It was helpful ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can make it easier :

```js
const msgTextEl = document.getElementById("msg-text")
const msgButtonEl = document.getElementById("msg-button")
const saveMsgEl = document.getElementById("save-msg")

// EVENT ON CLICK
msgButtonEl.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // CREATE A NODE AND APPEND TO SAVE-MSG
  let tmpMsg = document.createElement('li')
  tmpMsg.textContent = msgTextEl.value;
    saveMsgEl.appendChild(tmpMsg)
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>I want to pass this message to all:</h1>
  <input type="text" id="msg-text" size="100%">
  <button id="msg-button">Click to Save</button>
  <h2 class="save-title">Save the Message Below:</h2>
  <p id="save-msg"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('msg-button');
let container = document.getElementById('save-msg');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let inputData = document.getElementById('msg-text').value;
  let newElement = document.createElement('p');
  newElement.innerHTML = inputData;
  container.appendChild(newElement);
  container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<br />');
  
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <h1>I want to pass this message to all:</h1>
    <input type="text" id="msg-text" size="100%">
    <button id="msg-button">Click to Save</button>
    <h2 class="save-title">Save the Message Below:</h2>
    <p id="save-msg"></p
  
</div>
```